# TypeScript cannot find namespace in Node.js dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have two node.js packages containing type declaration files.
I have a namespace declared in package `a` that I would like to reference in package `b`.

### Package A

**index.d.ts**

```js
declare namespace foo {
    export interface A {}
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

### Package B

**index.d.ts**

```js
declare namespace bar {
    const A: foo.A;
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "file:../a"
  }
}
```

### Error

```
$ cd b
$ npm install
$ tsc --noEmit index.d.ts

index.d.ts:3:14 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'foo'.

3     const A: foo.A;
               ~~~


Found 1 error.
```

How get I get package `b` to see the `namespace` declared in package `a`? Here's a repo with the code https://github.com/icholy/typescript_problem_example

Comment: Where is `foo` declared? You mean `thing`?

Comment: I've updated the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution I found is to import the module as a type.

```
declare namespace bar {
    type _ = import('a');
    const A: foo.A;
}
```

Another solution is to use a [Tripple-Slash Directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to add a direct reference to `a`.

```
/// <reference types="a" />

declare namespace bar {
    const A: foo.A;
}
```